# integrate $ \int \frac {x dx}{\sqrt {1+x^{10}} } $

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

This is a tough one. Thanks.

$$\int \frac {x dx}{\sqrt {1+x^{10}} } $$

This is not a homework problem. I spend 10 hours over the course of 3 days on this. I tried:

1) substituting u for x^5 to get a tangent-like quantity in the denominator

2)subsituting u for 1+x^10

3) substituting u for sqrt(1+x^10)

4) integration by parts. This leaves me with $$\int \frac { dx}{\sqrt {1+x^{10}} } $$ which I still find difficult.

5). Multiplying denominator and numerator by sqrt(1+x^10), and then integrating.

Comment: or $$ \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^5}}du $$ still non trivial. Also, please check out this [eqworld](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/) as it may hold hints for you now and in the future :).

Comment: [WRA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+1%2Fsqrt%281%2Bx^5%29+dx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can at least simplify this integral somewhat via the substitution $u=x^2$:

$$\int\frac{x\,\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1+x^{10}}}=\frac12\int\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\sqrt{1+u^5}}.$$

Next, substituting $t=-u^5$ puts the integral in a form recognizable as the [definition of an incomplete beta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevIntegral.html): for non-negative $t$,

$$\frac12\int\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\sqrt{1+u^5}}=\frac{\sqrt[5]{-1}}{10}\int\frac{t^{-\frac45}}{\sqrt{1-t}}\mathrm{d}t=\frac{\sqrt[5]{-1}}{10}\operatorname{B}{\left(t;\frac15,\frac12\right)}+\text{const}.$$

Answer (score 4):

> *I spend $10$ hours over the course of $3$ days on this*.

You shouldn't have. Antiderivatives of the form $~\displaystyle\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt[n]{1+x^m}}~$ and $~\displaystyle\int\sqrt[n]{1+x^m}~dx~$, with both

*m* and *n* natural numbers, cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions, unless either $m=1,~$ or $~m,n\le2$. This can be proven using either [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) or the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm), though I think that goes beyond the scope of this question. So unless you didn't have the definite

integral $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{\sqrt[n]{1+x^m}}~$ in mind, which returns an expression in terms of the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), as

can be shown by letting $t=\dfrac1{1+x^m}$ , I am afraid that the only closed forms available are those in

terms of [hypergeometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) or [elliptic integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral), where the former can be obtained by simply expanding the integrand into its [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series), and then switching the order of summation and integration.

Comment: the problem is actually supposed to include integration limits from $e^{-pi}$ to $e^{pi}$... I saw the problem on an exam posted online somewhere. I guess there was context there that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: Putting the series into a recognizable form is not the easiest task. Especially when dealing with the hypergeometric series/function

Comment: @animalcroc: Have you tried breaking up the interval $(e^{-\pi},e^\pi)$ into $(e^{-\pi},1)$ and $(1,e^\pi)$, then letting $t=\dfrac1x$ in one of the two resulting integrals ?

Comment: @TylerHG: The result is $~x~_2F_1\bigg(\dfrac1m,\pm\dfrac1n,1+\dfrac1m,-x^m\bigg)$.

Comment: Yea WA was telling me this, but I can't get the series in the right form! I can't figure out how to get the other two Pochhammer symbols. Maybe I'll post a new question. @Lucian

Comment: Thanks guys. I think it's best to leave it as is. I don't think there's anything more enlightening than what's been posted.